# Can a template function be called with missing template parameters in C++ ?

Tags: c++, class, templates, function-templates

This is an interview question, which has been done.

Which line has error ?

```
  #include<iostream>
  template<class T> void foo(T op1, T op2)
  {
      std::cout << "op1=" << op1 << std::endl;
      std::cout << "op2=" << op2 << std::endl;
  }

  template<class T>
  struct sum
  {
      static void foo(T op1, T op2)
      {
              std::cout << "sum=" << op2 << std::endl ;
      }
  };

  int main()
  {
      foo(1,3);  // line1
      foo(1,3.2);  // line2
      foo<int>(1,3);  // line3
      foo<int>(1, '3') ; // line 4
      sum::foo(1,2) ; // line 5  , 

      return 0;
  }
```

Line 2 has error because the template parameter is not matching the definition. 
Line 5 has error because the template parameter is missing.

But, Line 1 is an not an error, I do not know why, does not it also miss template parameter  ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called type deducition.

On Line 1, the type of `T` can be deduced because parameters `op1` and `op2` are both `int`, making `T` an `int`.

Whereas on Line 2, you are passing both an int and a double while the function accepts both parameters as `T`, the compiler has no clue whether `T` should be a `double` or an `int`.

Line 3 is fine because you specify `int` specialization and pass `int`s in as well (making the specialization redundant but perfectly OK).

Line 4 is OK because you declare `T` to be an int, then casting the `char` value of `'3'` to its numeric `int` value.

Line 5 is an error because you're accessing a function that gets its type from the templated struct it's in, and type deduction only works for functions.

Comment: (1) C++ doesn’t know about ASCII. (2) There is no type deduction for class templates. It not only “doesn’t work”, it simply doesn’t exist.

Comment: @Konrad yes, that's correct. I've clarified my response. Thanks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph and Mahmoud Al-Qudsi , I am still confused why line 1 has no errors. Does C++ support type deduction or not ? thanks !

Comment: @user1002288 Isn't clear from the answer? Yes! C++ does use type deduction when possible, i.e. for function templates as in line 1. This is very handy as it allows massive function overloading.

Answer (score 0):

When we use a function template, the compiler infers what **template argument(s)** to bind to the template parameter(s). Once the compiler determines the actual template argument(s), it **instantiates** an instance of the function for us. Essentially the compiler figures out what type to use in place of each type parameter. So, if `op1` and `op2` have the same type the template parameter(s) can be omitted (that's why line #2 causes error).

From *C++ primer*